# How to derive the closed form of the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n d (i - 1)$?

Tags: summation, closed-form

I want to derive the closed form of

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n d  (i - 1)$$

d is a constant

Don't be harsh on me as I am getting back to math after some years of not using it ;)

I am finding only the result online, but for learning purpose I would love a step by step proof.

Meanwhile I am reading for a while finite calculus as in the end I want not only to understand, but do this myself.

Thank you!

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n i=\dfrac12n(n+1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n$.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KZFtj-aTVI

Comment: @Nosrati, thank you but that is what I am trying to proof xd. I found out the formula sumAtNth = firstElement + aboveSumation. Now I want to find the closed form of the sumation posted here. I want to derive a formulae and proof in which I can express the Nth sum of an arithmetic expression based on its first element and difference between terms.

Comment: it's closed form is $\dfrac{dn(n-1)}{2}$ can you prove it with induction?

Comment: @Nosrati, yes I can prove with induction now that I have the closed form already. My question is, what is the systematic approach to find the closed form when we have no clue what it might be. Or the only solution is intuition and then prove with induction ?

Comment: In hard problems intuition is a effective tool, but such these easy problems there are many formulas one may use I think.

Comment: Ok thanks! I know that there are already proven formulas, and based on them we can further prove others. I just wanted to derive the closed form myself dn(n−1)2 instead of taking for granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we want:
$$S=\sum_{r=1}^n d(r-1)$$
and we know that this is a summation where each term of $(r-1)$ is being multiplied by $d$, so we can say that this is the same as the whole summation multiplied by d, hence:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n d(r-1)=d\sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)$$
now we can split this into two different summations:
$$d\sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)=d\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r-\sum_{r=1}^n 1\right)$$
There is a known general formula for the summation of r:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and we can see than $n$ lots of $1$ is just $n$, so:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n1=n$$
so our summation becomes:
$$S=d\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n\right)=\frac{dn(n-1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It holds 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n d(i-1)  = d \sum_{i=1}^n (i-1) =  d\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i = d\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i.$$
(Why?) The final task is to calculate the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i$. This can be done by a reordering, see for example [here](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/).

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} d * (i - 1) = d\sum_{i=1}^{n} i -1 $

We can then observe that the summation is just 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1), this will add up to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
Hence, final answer should be equals to $\frac{dn(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok so the systematic approach to find the closed form is purely intuitive, right ? I thought that I could learn some steps do that. By from your answer seems like the only way is to manually investigate the serie and derive the closed form yourself, then prove it by induction.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further on what you are looking for? Maybe I can try to help. What kind of steps are you trying to learn?

Comment: Sure. I am trying to derive a formula in which I can express the sum at the nth position of an arithmetic progression by it's position N and difference d only. I have  arrived until sumAtNthPos = N * firstElement + ∑ni=1d∗(i−1). Now to finish deriving my formulae, I want to find the closed form of the summation posted here. And I want to do that in a systematic way, not just taking the result for granted.

Comment: Could you format the latex a little better? I can't really understand the equation.

Comment: $Sn = N * A1 + sum_{i=1}^n d * (i - 1)$

Comment: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83480/discussion-between-statsguy21-and-kristi-jorgji).

Answer (score 1):

$S:= d \sum _{i=1}^{n} (i-1);$

$S = d[ 1+2+3+....(n-1)]$; or

in reverse order:

$S=d[(n-1)+(n-2)+..+2+1]$.

Add term by term:

$2S =$

$d [(1+(n-1))+ (2+(n-2))+..$

$...+((n-1)+1)];$

There are $n-1$ summands, each equals $n$.

Hence

$2S= $

$d[n +n +....n+n] = d[(n-1)n];$

$S=(1/2)d(n-1)n$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the insights, each provides a hint to what I want to learn !

The link below explains how Gauss derived the closed form of the summation from:
$$S_N = \sum_{i=1}i$$
to
$$S_N = N(N + 1) / 2$$

http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/

I also found this useful (Triangular numbers):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: Kristi.You may enjoy this story of Gauss, famous German mathematician(purported).https://www.nctm.org/Publications/Teaching-Children-Mathematics/Blog/The-Story-of-Gauss/

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks for the link. Really good explanation on how to derive the closed form of the sum by intuition. What do you mean by purported though ? (PS: English isn't my primary language, even after searching online could not really understand the meaning in your context)

Comment: Kristi. Purported: The story as is told is possibly not true.(But that does not really matter). Sometimes for fun I ask kids to sum the first , say, 50 numbers, i.e 1+2+...+...50, and then show them the trick to write the numbers in reverse order below each other, etc.etc.and get the result much faster.Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The highest power of $i$ in your sum is $1$, so we can try to fit a $1+1=2$nd degree polynomial in $n$:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n d(i-1)=An^2+Bn+C$$
Substituting in $n=1$ we get that:
$$0=A+B+C$$
And with $n=2$:
$$d=4A+2B+C$$
And with $n=3$:
$$3d=9A+3B+C$$
So you have a system of $3$ linear equation, which you can solve: $A=\frac{d}{2}$, $B=-\frac{d}{2}$, $C=0$.
From this, we might have that (we don't know that if it's true for $n>3$)
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n d(i-1)=\frac{d}{2}n^2-\frac{d}{2}n$$
But you can (try to) prove it with induction.

And it works for higher powers too, for example, you can get a closed form for
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i^6-2i^5+93i^2+i)$$
as a $6+1=7$th degree polynomial in $n$:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i^6-2i^5+93i^2+i)=A_0+A_1n+A_2n^2+A_3n^3+A_4n^4+A_5n^5+A_6n^6+A_7n^7$$
But it will be a bit harder to solve the system of $7$ linear equations.